# Getting a null pointer exception when trying to assign variable

Tags: apex, trigger, data, import, process

I keep getting a null pointer exception but I can't understand why. I do have null checks. I know that the field on the Match__c is null, but I can't understand why that would matter, since it's the field being assigned to.

```
 if ( taskMap.get(tId).whatId != null && 
    taskMap.get(tId).whatId.getSObjectType() == Match__c.sObjectType) {
    if (taskMap.get(tId).Subject.containsIgnoreCase('Student Started Learning') 
        && taskMap.get(tId).Call_Outcome__c != null) {
            matchesMap.get(taskMap.get(tId).whatId).Call_Outcome_Student_Started_Learning__c 
                = taskMap.get(tId).Call_Outcome__c;
    }
```

I know `matchesMap.get(taskMap.get(tId).whatId).Call_Outcome_Student_Started_Learning__c` is null, but it is the variable being assigned to, so why would that be an issue?

Comment: If the error is thrown from that line it looks like it could be one of two things. That `taskMap.get(tId)` is null (which we know it isn't based on your null check above), or `matchesMap.get(taskMap.get(tId).whatId)` is null. Can you confirm neither are null?

Comment: @antonioManente you are a gentleman and a scholar thank you. It was the latter

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing value in your map. So add containsKey check before getting value out of map.

```
if (taskMap.containKey(tId) && taskMap.get(tId).whatId != null &&
    taskMap.get(tId).whatId.getSObjectType() == Match__c.sObjectType) {

    if (taskMap.get(tId).Subject.containsIgnoreCase('Student Started Learning') && 
    taskMap.get(tId).Call_Outcome__c != null && 
    matchesMap.containsKey(taskMap.get(tId).whatId)) {

    matchesMap.get(taskMap.get(tId).whatId).Call_Outcome_Student_Started_Learning__c = taskMap.get(tId).Call_Outcome__c;
    }
```